# pandas read_csv clear cache reading from URL (clear temp files)

Tags: python, pandas

I am using pandas' `read.csv` to read data from a URL (through an API), I think I am making a fresh request every time but the data provider is not seeing all my requests--only some.

Does pandas cache CSVs anywhere? If so is there a way to clear it or make sure that the data being read is refreshed every time?

When I read a csv from a URL does pandas download a temp file to some location? I tried finding it info on this in the docs but couldn't. Checked the package directory/temp folders and didn't see anything that looked like it.